# как вытащить из БД redshift определенное значение из строки через postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, substring, redshift

Имеются вот такие поля

| event_value | lvl |
| --- | --- |
| {"af_level":"19"} |  |
| {"af_level":"2"} |  |

Нужно из поля `event_value`, которое имеет формат redshift вытащить только значение уровня с помощью `postgreSQL`

Пробовала через такую конструкцию `substring(event_value, 14)`.
Результат выводит такой [image: введите сюда описание изображения].
В таком случае не знаю как выкинуть оставшиеся ненужные элементы строки

Если подставить второй аргумент `substring(event_value, 14, 2)`, то с двузначными числами становиться все как надо, с однозначными нет [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Это не формат "redshift", это JSON.

Надо сконвертировать строку к типу JSON, а потом уже читать поле с помощью оператора `->>`

```
with d as (
  select '{"af_level":"19"}' event_value
  union all select '{"af_level":"1"}'
) 
select event_value::json->>'af_level' from d
```

Вот тут больше операторов, на будущее https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html